# What does 事実だけがでんと構えてる mean?

Tags: meaning

What does 事実だけがでんと構えてる mean?
My breakdown of this sentence is, although I'm sure it's wrong:

事実だけが = the fact is
でんと = formally/officially
構えてる = start something/ establish something

So the sentence translated is: The fact of the matter is, something was established. Is this correct? I think there could be some nuance I'm missing though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [でん(と)](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/en/%E3%81%A7%E3%82%93/#je-102503) is an onomatopoeia for (the subject  presenting itself) *grand* or *big*.

構える here means [ある態度をとる](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/en/%E6%A7%8B%E3%81%88%E3%82%8B/#je-13398) or simply *to exist*.

The linked entries have relevant examples:

> 彼はでんと構えて動こうともしなかった
>
> He had 「planted himself in the chair [《口》 plunked himself down very firmly] and showed no sign of moving.
>
> 部屋には大きな机がでんと置いてあった
>
> A big desk was placed ostentatiously [conspicuously] in the room.
>
> いかにも[大家]{たいか}らしく構えている
>
> He has the bearing [air] of an important person.

So the sentence in the question means literally *The fact alone is there firmly*. (I guess this is not a good translation, but makes sense in the context.)